# Calculating the time of an Insert Sort and a Merge Sort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

I am taking a class in programming and have started algorithm analysis. The question given is to calculate the sorting time for an insert sort and a merge sort of 1e6 and 1e9 numbers given that both take 1 second to sort 1e3 numbers.

I am not sure if I understand time complexity fully, but since Insert Sort has O(n^2) and merge sort has O(n log n), this is how I am thinking:

If using insert sort takes 1 second to sort 1e3 numbers, increasing the amount of numbers to sort by a factor of 1e3, then the time increases by a factor of 1e3^2, or 1e6 seconds. The same goes for sorting 1e9 numbers, we increase the sorting time by a factor of 1e6^2, or 1e12 seconds. Am I thinking about this correctly?

As for the merge sort, if sorting 1e3 numbers (roughly 2^10) takes 1 second, sorting 1e6 numbers (roughly 2^20) increases the sorting time by a factor of 2^20 * 20, or roughly 2e7 seconds. Sorting 1e9 numbers (roughly 2^30) increases the sorting time by a factor of 2^30 * 30, or about 3.2e10 seconds. Is this correct?

As I stated, I am not sure I understand time complexity, so if this is wrong, how am I supposed to think about this?

Comment: You know what is the time complexities of those algorithms but didn't they teach you the definition of time complexity before that?

Comment: I'd be careful with the sentence "If using insert sort takes 1 second to sort 1e3 numbers, increasing the ammount of numbers to sort by a factor of 1e3, then the time increases by 1e3^2, or 1e6 seconds". The time is multiplied by a **factor** of 1e6. Although it does result in a total of 1e6 seconds, your formulation is misleading and I suggest correcting it.

Comment: @Stef Fixed that now. English is not my native language, so some grammatical errors are bound to pop up, haha.

Comment: @mangusta Well, they have taught us the definitions. I am just not sure that I completley understand how it is used, as in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insertion sort

Your reasoning for insertion sort is correct.

I'd be careful with the sentence "If using insert sort takes 1 second to sort 1e3 numbers, increasing the amount of numbers to sort by a factor of 1e3, then the time increases by 1e3^2, or 1e6 seconds". The time is multiplied by a factor of 1e6. Although it does result in a total of 1e6 seconds as you correctly stated, your wording is misleading and I suggest correcting it.

### Merge sort

As for merge sort, the calculation is slightly more complex because of the logarithm. Imagine there is a constant `k` such that the execution time of merge sort is always exactly `k * n * log(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements to be sorted.

You are given: `k * 1e3 log(1e3) = 1s`. You want to figure out the value of `k * 1e6 log(1e6)`.

The good news is that by properties of logarithm, `log(1e6) = log((1e3)^2) = 2 log(1e3)`. Therefore `k * 1e6 log(1e6) = k * 1e6 * 2 * log(1e3) = (2e3) * (k * 1e3 * log(1e3))`. Thus the running time of merge sort on an entry of 1e6 elements is 2e3 seconds.

The reasoning for 1e9 is the same as for 1e6, so I will let you find out by yourself.

### Sanity check

Insertion sort runs in time proportionate to `n^2`. Merge sort runs in time proportionate to `n log(n)`. Logarithm is a very slow function; when `n` starts getting large, the running time of merge sort is much shorter than the running time of insertion sort.

Your initial answers were: on an entry of 1e6 elements, insertion sort takes 1e6 seconds and merge sort takes 2e7 seconds. This cannot be correct. 2e7 seconds = 20,000,000s is 20 times longer than 1e6 seconds = 1,000,000s!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!! So, following the same reasoning I get that 1e9 numbers the time increases by a factor of 3e6. Sounds about right?